# Django Admin Image/Document Uploader/Manager

Tags: django, upload, admin, document

I need a simple Django application that enables me to upload and manage (list, delete, show URL) files (pdf, image, whatever - just file based) via the admin interface. I don't need any image manipulation capabilities or other features.

Is there such an app? I found django-admin-uploads, but it's not what I need. I'll use the URLs on my own.

Comment: The offerings in this space are incredibly limited. I have asked my own questions about this, and performed my own research.

Comment: @Marcin What was the result? Did you implent this on your own?

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a purely custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but if you write a simple app
which just has the data you want to track, and includes a FileField - i.e:

```
class MyList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = '/path/to/uploads')
```

then register that with the admin app
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

If you want some more flexibility on the admin interface, try out grappelli or django-admin-tools